# RelativeSource returns null in ContentPresenter

Tags: .net, wpf

My problem can be reduced to this simplified example:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="first">
        <Button Content="TestButton" />
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="second">
        <ContentPresenter >
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <Button x:Name="button" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}" 
                        Content="CommandParameter is null" Click="OnButtonClick" />
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If you select second tab then button's `CommandParameter=null`. But if `IsSelected="True"` is set initially for second `TabItem`, then `CommandParameter` has correct value.

My workaround for this problem required using `ContentTemplate` property. Also I could use `ContentControl` (but not in mine case, because `ContentPresenter` is used inside of control's style template).

1. Because TabControl and ContentPresenter used widely in my application I would like to know the reason for such behavior - any ideas?
2. What other ways to deal with this issue?

Comment: You shouldn't have styles for `ContentPresenter` really. Also, `ContentControl`s default `ContentTemplate` contains a `ContentPresenter`, so I don't understand why this would break the styling. Actually, I wouldn't use `ContentPresenter` at all for XAML content, only inside `ControlTemplate` and for MVVM viewmodels as content, that would be presented by a `DataTemplate` with matching `DataType`.